# jQuery datepicker minDate variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm usung the jQuery datepicker. In my "EndDate" textbox I'd like to use the date selected from the the "StartDate" textbox + 1. How do I do this?

I tried this but didn't work. In my start date code I had...

```
            test = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            testm = new Date(test.getTime());
            testm.setDate(testm.getDate() + 1);
```

Then in my end date code I had...

```
minDate: testm,
```

but the end date still made all the days for the month available.

---

**Edit.** I'm curious as to why this doesn't work. In my start date datepicker I have this..

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
    test = dateText
}
```

Why can't I come down into my end date datepicker and say, `minDate: test`?

---

**Edit.** Still not working

```
    $(".dateStartDatePickerBox").datepicker({
        minDate:'-0d',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
        {
            test = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            testm = new Date(test.getTime());
            testm.setDate(testm.getDate() + 1);

            $("#dateEndDatePickerBox").datepicker("option", "minDate", testm);
        }
    });

    $(".dateEndDatePickerBox").datepicker({
        onSelect: function()
        {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll need to set the min date dynamically on the change event of the start date.

Something like:

```
$("#startDate").change(function() {
    test = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    testm = new Date(test.getTime());
    testm.setDate(testm.getDate() + 1);

    $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", testm);
});
```

**Answer to the edit:**

You cannot do the following:

```
var test;
$("#myinput").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { test = $(this).datepicker("getdate"); }
});
$("#myotherinput").datepicker({
    minDate: test
});
```

Test is uninitialized at the time that minDate is being set on `myotherinput`. The process of setting the minDate doubtless requires DOM manipulation which datepicker manages on initialization or when "option" is called. Simply changing the variable that was used for initialization does not effect the already initialized datepicker.

Comment: Joel, I tried that. But after picking say, 3/23/2010 in my start date. The end date options for this month were still available. The goal here is to have, in this example, them start at 3/24/2010.

Comment: This method is working here: http://jsbin.com/uvehu/edit. Please provide more context and code if it's still not working for you.

Comment: Joel, I can see that example working. I'll edit my original post to show the code I have. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Joel, my hunch is that with the code I have. This line in the start date code - $("#dateEndDatePickerBox").datepicker("option", "minDate", testm); is not being seen by the end date code. Do I have that in the wrong place?

Comment: Thank you Joel. Your example was right on. The reason my edit was not working was because I had this - $("#dateEndDatePickerBox") when I needed the . like this $(".dateEndDatePickerBox") Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking setting a max selection date?

```
StartDate = new Date("March 20, 2010");
EndDate = new Date("March 21, 2010");

$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: StartDate, maxDate: EndDate, defaultDate: StartDate  });
```

Note the maxDate? That won't let you select any days past it ...

Comment: Justin, that's close. Let me explain a bit more. In your example StartDate...I need to have that be the date selected from my start date calendar. Then for the EndDate I need to say, whatever that date was that was selected + 1.

Answer (score 0):

The API [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-minDate) for the date picker does seem to say it should take a Date object, but I've had this exact problem in the past and this is how I solved it.

Pass `minDate` an *offset*, instead of a date. You'll need a function to take your start date, add one to it and then get the offset from today. So you could have a function like:

```
function offsetFromToday( someDate ) {
  // clear time offset because we only want to take date into account
  someDate.setHours( 0 );
  someDate.setMinutes( 0 );

  // The number of milliseconds in one day
  var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  someDate = someDate.getTime();
  var today = new Date().getTime();

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference = Math.abs( someDate - today );

  // Convert back to days and return
  return Math.floor( (difference / ONE_DAY) + 1 );
}
```

So you just need to get your start date a day ahead: `StartDate.setDate( StartDate.getDate() + 1 )` or similar, and then pass it to this function to get an offset, then give *that* to `minDate`.

Comment: thenduks, I'm not completely clear on where would this be called from with what I currently have. Can you look at my last edit and tell me where I'd have this?

Comment: btw - in my last edit, I think, that'll work but that I have this line - $("#dateEndDatePickerBox").datepicker("option", "minDate", testm); in the wrong place and the end date datepicker is not seeing it. I'm not sure on to implement that line in the end date datepicker.