# How to update the minDate value of jQuery DatePicker?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, mindate

I have the following function to set the default value of minDate:

```
$(function() {
$( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker();
$( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker('option','minDate','<?php echo $minDate ?>');       
});
```

But after the page load the $minDate variable sometimes change based on the earliest date in some of my function.

Example if the value of $minDate is "7/29/2012" and after the page is fully loaded sometimes the $mindDate date changes to earlier than "7/29/2012". Say it will change to "7/20/2012".

If this happens I want to change the minDate value of DatePicker to the new date (i.e. "7/20/2012" instead of "7/29/2012").

How to call this function?

UPDATE*
Example code:

```
<?php
    $checkin = "7/29/2012";
    $minDate = $checkin;
?>
<head>
    $(function() {
        $( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker();
        $( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker('option','minDate','<?php echo $minDate ?>');       
    });
</head>

<body>
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $r_id=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['room_id'];

        if (!isset($room_id)){
            $room_id=$r_id;
        }else{
            $room_id=$room_id . "," . $r_id;
        }

        $checkin=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['checkin'];
        $checkout=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['checkout'];
        $nights=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['nights'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $pname=get_room_type($r_id);

        if ($checkin < $minDate) $minDate = $checkin; //<--- here...how can I change the minDate of datepicker to the new value?
    }
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please note that the checkin date is stored in an array in a session.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you can so this.

```
$(function() {
 $( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker();
 $( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(<?php echo $checkin ?>) });
});


$( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
```

Please refer this link. this may help you. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: how can I call this line: `$( "#arrival_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );`

Comment: This one you can use when you want to set the date dynamically on the page through javascript based on some scenario. As in the demo they are setting it based on the other date selection.

Comment: can I call this using PHP? How? based on my sample above the $minDate changed its value when $checkin is less than $minDate.

Comment: See php code will not execute on html page. This will work only for the first time while rendering. So you can setup while loading the page as shown in the first 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

This is taken from an earlier stackoverflow post but it should help you solve your problem

[jQuery datepicker minDate variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484631/jquery-datepicker-mindate-variable)

```
$("#checkinDate").change(function() {     
    test = $(this).datepicker('getDate');     
    testm = new Date(test.getTime());     
    testm.setDate(testm.getDate() + 1);      
    $("#arrival_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", testm); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know when or how checkin changes, but maybe something like..

```
$checkin.change(function () {
    newDate = $(this).val();
    $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ 
        minDate: new Date(newDate) 
    });
});
```