# Jquery datepicker min max setting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

By setting

```
minDate: "-1M", 
maxDate: "+1M",
```

I am getting **minDate as 24/Aug/2012** and **maxDate as 24/oct/2012**.
I want minDate as Start date of previous month i.e  **01/Aug/2012** and maxDate as end date of next month **31/oct/2012**.

How should i configure date picker to get it?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484631/jquery-datepicker-mindate-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the dates yourself:

```
var minDate = new Date();
minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth()-1, 1);
var maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth()+2, 0);
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    ...
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    ...
});
```

Comment: for next months last date is should be  maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth()+2,0);