# jquery datepicker get minDate (formatted to mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using jQuery datePicker, I set minDate to "-3y".

When I call:

```
$mydatepicker.datepicker("option", "minDate")
```

I get

```
-3y
```

Is it possible using datePicker methods to get it as mm/dd/yyyy?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately datepicker does not offer a public API that handles relative dates, just internal methods that do that.
Consider calculating the minDate server side - that is what I ended up doing.

If you still absolutely need it:

```js
// DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION CODE!!
var minDate = $.datepicker._getMinMaxDate( $mydatepicker.data('datepicker'), 'min' ),
    zeroPad = function( toPad, padToLength ) {
        toPad = toPad.toString();
        var i = toPad.length;
        while( i < padToLength  )
            toPad = '0' + toPad, i++;

        return toPad;
    }
    formattedMinDate = zeroPad( minDate.getMonth(), 2 ) + '/'
                       zeroPad( minDate.getDay(), 2 ) + '/'
                       minDate.getFullYear();
```

**Please note that the code above is -bad-** and you should **not** be using it as it relies on private methods that might disappear without notice in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You should do

```
var date = $mydatepicker.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
var date = $mydatepicker.datepicker('getDate');
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
```

If you want it as an object, you can remove the `.val()`

More Info available at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
and [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/)

Comment: I'm aware of formatDate, but I'm not sure how to tell it to format a minDate of "-3y".

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484631/jquery-datepicker-mindate-variable